# I am having issues with a for loop in node.js with express in production, but not development mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having issues with a for loop in node.js with express in production, but not in development mode.

For whatever reason when I push to production the xTickValues array is empty, and my for loop is not pushing the values to the array. Why would this not work in production?

**Here's the for loop**

```js
var daysToCount =  29; 
var dayOfYearStart = 91
var xTickValues = [];
       

// right here
for (let i = 0; i < daysToCount; i++) {
  var xTick = i + dayOfYearStart;
  xTickValues.push(xTick);
}


console.log(xTickValues, 'this is xtick values')
```

**Here's the result I want for xTickValues. In development the for loop works, but in production it's an empty array**

```js
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
```

**Here's the full file**

```js
const User = require("../../models/User");
const { IS_ADMIN, CAN_ACCESS_CHARTS } = require("../../utils/enums");
const { ADMIN_ONLY_MESSAGE } = require("../../utils/defaultErrorMessages");
const isEmpty = require("../../utils/is-empty");
const Validator = require("validator");
const {
  intervalToDuration,
  eachDayOfInterval,
  format: dateFormat,
  addDays,
} = require("date-fns");

const getDayOfYearFromDate = require("../../utils/getDayOfYearFromDate");

const validateReqQuery = (data) => {
  let errors = {};
  data.startDate = !isEmpty(data.startDate) ? data.startDate : "";

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.startDate)) {
    errors.startDate = "startDate is required";
  }

  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors),
  };
};

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateReqQuery(req.query);

  //Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(500).json(errors);
  }
  try {
    let adminUser = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }).select(
      "permissions"
    );

    let { limit, startDate, xRangeType = "days", endDate } = req.query;
    let tempStartDate = dateFormat(new Date(startDate), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    let tempEndDate = addDays(new Date(startDate), 30);

    if (req.query.endDate) {
      tempEndDate = dateFormat(new Date(endDate), "MM/dd/yyy");
    }

    let dayOfYearStart = getDayOfYearFromDate(new Date(tempStartDate));
    let dayOfYearEnd = getDayOfYearFromDate(new Date(tempEndDate));

    let { days: daysToCount } = intervalToDuration({
      start: new Date(tempStartDate),
      end: new Date(tempEndDate),
    });
    let xTickFormat = [];

    var dayLabelsTemp = eachDayOfInterval({
      start: new Date(tempStartDate),
      end: new Date(tempEndDate),
    });


    dayLabelsTemp.forEach((day) => {
      let tempDay = dateFormat(day, "MMM-dd");
      xTickFormat.push(`${tempDay}`);
    });

    let dataSets = [];
    let dataSetLabels = [];

    let xKey = xRangeType || "days";
    let yKey = "count";
    let xTickValues = [];
    let numerator = 0;
    let denominator = 0;

    // right here
    for (let i = 0; i < daysToCount; i++) {
      let xTick = i + dayOfYearStart;
      xTickValues.push(xTick);
    }

    if (
      adminUser.permissions.includes(IS_ADMIN) ||
      adminUser.permissions.includes(CAN_ACCESS_CHARTS)
    ) {
      let totalUsers = await User.find().countDocuments();
      let users = await User.find(
        {
          lastTimeActive: {
            $gte: tempStartDate,
            $lt: tempEndDate,
          },
          permissions: {
            $nin: [IS_ADMIN],
          },
        },
        function (err, results) {
          results.forEach((result) => {
            if (
              !dataSetLabels.includes(result.lastUsedPlatform) &&
              result.lastUsedPlatform
            ) {
              dataSetLabels.push(result.lastUsedPlatform);
            }
          });
          numerator = results.length;
          denominator = totalUsers;
        }
      ).select("first_name last_name lastUsedPlatform lastTimeActive");

      let tempUserArray = new Array(...users);

      dataSetLabels.forEach((label, index) => {
        let tempArray = [];
        xTickValues.forEach((tick) => {
          tempArray.push({
            days: tick,
            count: 0,
            dataSetIndex: index,
          });
        });

        dataSets.push(tempArray);
      });

      let userItems = [];

      tempUserArray = tempUserArray.forEach(
        ({
          first_name,
          last_name,
          lastUsedPlatform,
          _id: userId,
          lastTimeActive,
        }) => {
          let indexToPushTo = xTickValues.find(
            (day) => day === getDayOfYearFromDate(lastTimeActive)
          );
          let dateIndex = dateFormat(lastTimeActive, "MMM-dd");
          let dayOfYearIndex = getDayOfYearFromDate(lastTimeActive);
          let item = {
            dateIndex,
            indexToPushTo,
            dayOfYearIndex,
            name: `${first_name} ${last_name}`,
            lastUsedPlatform: lastUsedPlatform,
            userId,

            parentIndex: dataSetLabels.indexOf(lastUsedPlatform),
          };

          userItems.push(item);
        }
      );

      userItems.forEach((user, index) => {
        let { parentIndex, dayOfYearIndex, lastUsedPlatform } = user;
        let columnToPush = dataSets[parentIndex].find(
          (item) => item.days === dayOfYearIndex
        );
        if (columnToPush) {
          columnToPush.count = columnToPush.count + 1;
          columnToPush.lastUsedPlatform = lastUsedPlatform;
        }
      });

      let payload = {
        chartTitle: "Platform Activity",
        dataSetLabels,
        dataSets,
        numerator,
        denominator,
        xKey,
        yKey,
        xTickValues,
        xTickFormat,
        startDate: tempStartDate,
        endDate: tempEndDate,
        yTickFormat: (x) => x,
      };

      return res.status(200).json(payload);
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: ADMIN_ONLY_MESSAGE });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    let errors = {};
    errors.err = err.toString();
    errors.endpoint = req.originalUrl;
    return res.status(500).json(errors);
  }
};
```

Comment: This code is very complex and a huge chunk of the behavior is wrapped in a `try`. Are you sure nothing is throwing in this `try` block? Regardless, this would be much easier to debug broken down into small, modular functions. Is `intervalToDuration` returning `days` correctly, e.g. `console.log(daysToCount)` shows the expected value?

Comment: daysToCount console.logs the right value, same with dayOfYearStart. 

It works in development mode. It generates a chart on the front end. 
but in production, the for loop does not work. and the dayToCount and dayOfYearStart are defined. @ggorlen

Comment: I get a res.status 200 on the front end with the payload information, I have confirmed that the route works fine, it's the for loop it is not waiting for